# Adding custom args to Paypal Woocommerce

Tags: php, paypal, woocommerce

I need to add custom args to PayPal paying link.

**The PHP function looks like this:**

```
$paypal_args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', $paypal_args );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args' , 'change_paypal_args' );

function change_paypal_args( $paypal_args ) {
  global $wp;
  global $woocommerce;
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

  $paypal_args['invoice'] = 'spi432';
  $paypal_args['txn_type'] = 'cart';
  $paypal_args['payment_date'] = $order->order_date;

    return $paypal_args;
}
```

I added `txn_type` and `invoice` as arguments to the link. But `payment_date` is not shown.

What may be the problem? Also, how can I display email of the customer?

Comment: Not showing where? Display customer email where? Your question isn't clear. Also check the [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/). Is `payment_date` even a supported argument? By the way, you can delete the first line of your code. `$paypal_args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', $paypal_args );` isn't doing anything.

Comment: In url that generate woo. Example: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&business=paypal%40west.com&no_note=1&currency_code=USD... + my additional args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enabled `WP_DEBUG` you would probably see that `$order_id` is undefined, and therefore `$order` is not an order object, so `$order->order_date` is likely a fatal error. Try passing the order as the second parameter instead.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args' , 'so_42424283_change_paypal_args', 10, 2 );

function so_42424283_change_paypal_args( $paypal_args, $order ) {

    $paypal_args['invoice'] = 'spi432';
    $paypal_args['txn_type'] = 'cart';

    // WC 2.6+
    $paypal_args['payment_date'] = $order->order_date;

    // WC 2.7
    //$paypal_args['payment_date'] = $order->get_date_created();

    return $paypal_args;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. But still cant get email of customer. Trying $paypal_args['payer_email'] = $order_meta['_billing_email'][0]; - no info in debug.

Comment: Just changed to $order->billing_email; and it works. Thank you a lot. Can you say - is it possible to rename arg? Change amount_1 to mc_gross for example.

Comment: Rename the args? I don't understand what you mean. PayPal expects specific parameters, but you can change their values.